# How to set gitlab proxy in golang?

Tags: git, go, proxy, gitlab, goland

There are some gitlab dependent modules in a golang project go.mod file and those gitlab modules I can only access using gitlab-proxy URL, not directly. One solution I have is to use gitlab-proxy URL everywhere instead of gitlab URL. But I am looking for some way to set gitlab-proxy in golang env or something so that golang automatically takes care of that. Any idea ?

One solution I have is to use gitlab-proxy URL everywhere instead of gitlab URL.
I am looking for some way to set gitlab-proxy in golang env or something so that golang automatically takes care of that.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the proxy environment variables in **Settings/Preferences | Go | Go Modules**?